# Codebreaker game

Tags: mathematics

[image]

This is a codebreaker game, and the codes can either be mathematical or abstract. Each entry in the second row must somehow be related to the entry in the first row that is in the same column. However, I'm having quite a hard time figuring this out... Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: Is this part of something wider, such as a game? Could there be hints around? Is there any other context?

Comment: This is from SEAMC (South East Asian Mathematics Competition), and players take turns trying to guess at the next entry. If everyone fails, they are given the new entry and it goes on again — however, I was not given the answer key to this :(

Comment: This might be too broad if you don't know the answer, since only two entries are provided.

Comment: I agree, but I'm trying to see what patterns are possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s from an active competition — see [the Help Center](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic "What topics can I ask about here?").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it

> JSMVYEKHNP?

Because

> to go from J to S you add 9 (so (4-1)*3). So you simply have to rotate J by (number - 1)*3 for each cell